# Silence Notifications?

Tags: notifications

Went to the sound profile of the apps, turned them all off or blocked them and still getting email notifications with a loud sound. IS there any way to turn them off, or what is the way to do this, without silencing the ringer? This happening through Gmail app.

Answer (score 0):

Press volume up/down button and then expand volume bar and lower the notifocation sound.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you go to more info section of the Gmail app (settings > application Manager > Gmail) uncheck "show notifications". This will turn off all notifications for Gmail.